# fade backgrounds move text up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have multiple background images that are behind a block of text each. I would like to fade each background image and have the text move up when one background image fades into another.

For example

BG1 (background image 1) has Tegxt1 on top of it. As BG1 fades into BG2, Text1 moves up and is replaced by Text2.

How can I do this with simple jquery and javascript and CSS?

Here's what I tried

```
this._currentTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    this.slides$.eq(newSlideIndex).css('z-index', 3).fadeTo(ANIMATION_FADE_DURATION, 1, function() {
        this.slides$.eq(this.currentSlideIndex).css('z-index', 1).css('opacity', 0);
        this.slides$.eq(newSlideIndex).css('z-index', 2);
        this.currentSlideIndex = newSlideIndex;

        this._setTransitionTimerForNewSlide(this._getNextSlideIndex(), 5000);
    }.bind(this));
}.bind(this), durationUntilTransition);
```

Comment: You can use CSS transitions  and animations

Comment: Please show your code and your attempt.  We can help you with the the z-index and transition of the text.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please see post I have what I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide enough code to generate a complete working example (How is your html structured? Where is your jQuery located on the page? What does your existing CSS look like?), so unfortunately no one on StackOverflow and give you a perfect answer. The best we can do is create a small demo of what you could do to accomplish this affect. It's then up to you to learn from the example and apply the concept to your own code.

If I was going to try to accomplish this, here's the approach I would take:

1. Stack images on top of each other with `position: absolute;`

   - The first image group should have the highest z-index, so it's on top. CSS can do this!
   - The second image group should have the second-highest z-index, so that it shows behind the first image during the fade. CSS again!
   - all other image_groups should have z-index below the second image. Yay for CSS!
2. Animate the image and text seperately

   - The image just needs to fade out
   - The text needs to fade up and out
3. After the first (top) image group is completely faded, move it to the bottom of the list
4. Remove the inline `style="..."` that jQuery's `.animate()` applies to the image group. Once we do this, the image group will adhere to the css rules we set up in step one.

[**JS Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/d2py5fe8/)

The first step will be done manually by you when you're writing HTML and CSS, but then your jQuery can handle steps 2-4. Then just repeat as much as you'd like. Ask questions if you need to, but try hard to apply this to your own code. Good luck!!